# Is it possible for a $.get to alert a http status code and create a table at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have 2 functions both of which does a separate GET call on my php file. I'm trying to do one $. GET call do different task

I'm changing this variable whenever I'm trying to get a 404 error.

```
 var url = "output-tv.php";
```

this is my function that alerts if it has 404 error

```
 $.ajax({
   url: url,
   statusCode:{
   404: function(){
   alert('Page not found');
 }
},          
 success: function(data){
   alert('success');    
   }
});
```

and this is my function that creates a table

```
 $.get(url,
  {tv_type:tv_type,screen_size:screen_size,connectivity:connectivity,features:features},
  function(response)
  {

  var i = 0;
  var table = document.getElementById("table")
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  $( ".result" ).html( statusCode );
  alert( "Load was performed." );

 $("#table td").remove();
 $(response.result).each(function () {
 var rowString = "<tr>";
 rowString += "<td>" + this.product_code + "</td>
 rowString += "<td>" + this.tv_name + "</td>";
 rowString += "<td>" + this.size + "</td>";
 rowString += "<td>" + this.tv_type + "</td>";
 rowString += "</tr>";
 $('#table').append(rowString);
 });
```

I've tried doing this but I can't catch the 404 error.

```
 $.get(url,
 {tv_type:tv_type,screen_size:screen_size,connectivity:connectivity,features:features},
 function(response, statusCode){

$(.result){
 statusCode:{
   404: function(){
   alert('Page not found');
 }
},          
 success: function(data){
   alert('success');
 }

 $("#table td").remove();
 $(response.result).each(function () {
 var rowString = "<tr>";
 rowString += "<td>" + this.product_code + "</td>";
 rowString += "<td>" + this.tv_name + "</td>";
 rowString += "<td>" + this.size + "</td>";
 rowString += "<td>" + this.tv_type + "</td>";
 rowString += "</tr>";
 $('#table').append(rowString);
 });

 }, "json" );
```

Comment: If I am correct, $.get accepts 3 params: params, successCallback, failCallback.

Comment: I've also seen that in w3schools and api.jquery.com but I'm having a hard time implementing that. I keep getting errors like missing '(' but when I added the '(' its showing another error.

Comment: Instead of $.get why don't you use $.ajax for GET request ? $.ajax has provision for options for getting error codes

Comment: I'm comfortable using $.get. But if I gave up looking for solutions and doing trial and error I would use $.ajax as a last resort

Answer (score 0):

with success and failure, you must use complete as well:

```
complete: function(xhr, data) {
        if (xhr.status == 404)
            // do something
        else
            //do something else
    }
```